# Set Group Description to HTML via PS Script

Tags: powershell, groups

I am using the following code/function to add groups to a site:

```
function Create-SPGroupInWeb 
{  
    param ($url, $groupName, $permissionLevel, $description)  
    try{
        $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $url
        if($web -ne $null){
            if ($web.SiteGroups[$groupName] -ne $null)  
            {  
                write-Host -f red "Group $groupName already exists!"
            }  
            else  
            {  
                $web.SiteGroups.Add($groupName, $web.Site.Owner, $web.Site.Owner, $description)  
                $group = $web.SiteGroups[$groupName]  
                $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)  
                $roleDefinition = $web.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions[$permissionLevel]  
                $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition)  
                $web.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)  
                $web.Update()
                write-Host "Group $groupName created successfully"
            }  

            $web.Dispose() 
        }
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
        write-host -f red $_.Exception.ToString()
    }
}


Create-SPGroupInWeb -url "http://my-webApp:port/" -groupName "New Group" -permissionLevel "Read" -description "My New Group Description"
```

Now, this works perfectly as is.
However, this does not like it if I use HTML Code...

The Issue is: It creates the description as Plain Text...

Q) How do I get it to accept or convert the Description to HTML?

Original Script used from: [Create Site Permission Groups and Add Users for SharePoint - Powershell](http://hemika-kodikara.blogspot.com/2012/12/create-site-permission-groups-and-add.html)

[image: Sample Output]
Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to add the HTML?  At the Create-SPGroupInWeb part?

Comment: Yes: e.g. Create-SPGroupInWeb -url "http://abc.com" -groupName "Group 1" -permissionLevel "Read" -description "This is my description with - <STRONG><U>My HTML Code</U></STRONG>"

Answer (score 1):

If your description is $description, you can try writing it as such.

```
$header = "<STRONG><U>"
$footer = "</U></STRONG>"
$myHTMLDescription = $description | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment -PreContent $header -PostContent $footer | Out-String
```

If that doesn't work for you, take a look at these two links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950645/convertto-html-outputting-pre-post-content-showing-up-as-system-string-instead

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849944.aspx

Comment: Yeah, of course! :)

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. It doesn't swear at me so the script does whatever the script does without error, but doesn't do what I want it to do. :/ I added an Image (need to open in new tab).

Comment: You could try taking a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  Although, I don't know if you want to edit the .aspx page

Comment: OR you could try to write it as $myDescription = SPEncode.HtmlEncode($description) if that works for you.

Comment: Still no luck. Decided to scrap that Idea for now, but will keep trying to find a solution. There might some stupid SP setting other than security that's preventing me from changing it. Thanks again for your Help. I will continue to update this post for future reference and knowledge sharing.